# How to get user phone number in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to take the user's phone number using my app. I will take the permission then a code will bring the number.

An example,
When My user runs the app it will request the user to give the permission, and then one function will be run and the number.

I have tried this to get the number.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 String simPhoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

I got the user's permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

It is returning **null**.
What can I do now?